# ResourceAcquisitionFailedException while creating a new node

Tags: neo4j

Users of an application that I work on are reporting this particular exception with neo4j 2.1.1.   This appears to be sporadic and difficult to reproduce.    Is this a known issue, or is it associated with any particular misuse or error?    I would love to provide more information on how to reproduce this, but I cannot.

The code that creates this stacktrace is really dead simple:

```
Node n = null;

try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {           
    n = db.createNode();
    // Lots of extra code snipped here because it never makes it that far...
}
```

The exception seems to be thrown on the `createNode()` method:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/plus] threw exception
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.ResourceAcquisitionFailedException: TM encountered an unexpected error condition.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager$ResourceHolder.enlist(PersistenceManager.java:412)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager$ResourceHolder.forWriting(PersistenceManager.java:394)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.ensureWriteTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:190)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.upgradeToDataTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:220)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelStatement.dataWriteOperations(KernelStatement.java:83)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.createNode(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1107)
        at org.mitre.provenance.db.neo4j.Neo4JStorage.store(Neo4JStorage.java:1101)
```

(big stack of servlet related exceptions snipped out here that)

At the bottom, there is this:

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Tx status is: STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:191)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager$ResourceHolder.enlist(PersistenceManager.java:405)
        ... 45 more
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. My stack trace is identical for all org.neo4j.kernel code except for some differing line numbers for some of the source file locations. I am running neo4j 2.1.6. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @JohnDeverall after upgrading, I was unable to reproduce this problem.  So I didn't exactly fix it with Stefan's answer, but I don't have the problem anymore.

Comment: I am also having trouble reproducing it due to its intermittent nature. I wonder which version of neo4j you are currently running?

Comment: Well it's been a while...I think when I went from 2.1.1 => 2.1.6 it disappeared.  But to be clear I'm not saying it went away, just that I can't reproduce.

Comment: I'm getting this one too. My version is 2.1.7. It fails when I do property modify from TimerTask.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of fixes have been applied since 2.1.1, so make sure to run on the latest stable version (2.1.4 as of today). If the problem persists on 2.1.4, consider filing a github issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new